# How can I update youtube-dl?

Tags: apt, updates, youtube

I use youtube-dl to download videos for watching later offline. Usually, it works fine. However, due to frequent changes on the video sites, it sometimes requires a quick update. It wasn't a problem before on 13.04 but after upgrading to 13.10, I get

```
# youtube-dl -U
It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.
```

I tried updating it via apt-get but there is no new package. So **the app's update mechanism has been disabled and the maintainers aren't keeping up, what is the solution? How do I update it?**

And why was it changed at all? It was updating a package manager version just fine in raring.

I'm already running into compatibility problems.

```
$ youtube-dl "http://vimeo.com/55784152"
[vimeo] 55784152: Downloading webpage
[vimeo] 55784152: Extracting information
ERROR: Unable to extract info section; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output. Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update.
```

QUICK UPDATE:

As requested,

```
# type youtube-dl
youtube-dl is hashed (/usr/bin/youtube-dl)

# apt-cache policy youtube-dl
youtube-dl:
  Installed: 2013.08.29-1
  Candidate: 2013.08.29-1
  Version table:
 *** 2013.08.29-1 0
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is the output of `type youtube-dl`? And `apt-cache policy youtube-dl`.

Comment: I added the outputs to the question. It should be all standard.

Answer (score 142):

First, uninstall the apt version.

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
```

Then, install youtube-dl with pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install --user youtube-dl
```

To update it afterwards, for Ubuntu 20.04+ (Python 3 being the default Python) try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

If you are using an older version of Ubuntu, or specifically want to use Python2, try:

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Note: this assumes you have **pip** or **pip3** installed. Avoid using `sudo pip3` ([use virtualenv instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028735/1991051)).

Using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) is a way to install youtube-dl, as reported on the [official youtube-dl website](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html), and the `--upgrade` option makes sure you end up with the latest available version installed.

To find out where youtube-dl has been installed, you can use the `pip3 show youtube-dl` command (see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_show/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028735/1991051)).

Comment: If pip is not installed, you can install it by `sudo apt install python-pip`

Comment: `pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl` for Ubuntju 20.04

Comment: This leaves me with two instances of youtube-dl. The older version apt-get installed. And the lastest version, which pip installed. But the one the runs when putting `youtube-dl` into the command line is the older one from apt-get. What's the way around this?

Comment: @inspirednz Remove the apt-get version, and reinstall the pip version, if it still does not show up when you call `youtube-dl`

Comment: How can I start the pip version of yt dl? It is in `dist-packages`, easiest is `python -m youtube-dl` and set an alias to e. g. `yt`.

Comment: sudo apt remove youtube-dl to remove the old apt-installed binary. Then you will need to (most likely) add ~/.local/bin to your search path.

Comment: Close your terminal and start it again to effect the changes.

Comment: How to update to the latest version for ubuntu 22.04? `youtube-dl --version` still shows `2021.12.17` even after `pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Answer (score 49):

I installed `youtube-dl` following the official homepage instructions: https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html because `youtube-dl` installed via `sudo apt-get install` didn't allow `sudo youtube-dl -U`.

To get `youtube-dl` from source:

```sh
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now, `sudo youtube-dl -U` works without problems and I currently see:

```
$ youtube-dl --version
2021.12.17
```

There you'll also find alternatives using `wget`, `pip3` or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up sticking the binary from their website in ~/bin. It works and will probably update itself fine (even without sudo/root) but I can't say that this is a satisfying solution.

Comment: What about when you're not using sudo?

Comment: @Anthony If you can't use `sudo` you have the `pip3` and the [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) way. I would alowys stick to [the official way](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) for installing and updating

Answer (score 13):

Try `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`.
I do get upgrades every couple of days and I think, according to the message You get, that it should solve/answer Your question.
If You did an upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 You might have forgot (I guess) to update sources-list.d folder, for example, if You used WebUpd8 before.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem with youtube-dl.

Using super user privileges in order to update it might solve your problem:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Comment: I'm running it as root. Note the # prompt.

Comment: Sorry, it was not apparent to me.

Comment: This is the way

Comment: Doesn't work when it's installed with apt. Gives the error: `youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian.`

Answer (score 5):

try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

then if you still get an error do this:

```
wget -O - https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl >/dev/null
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 3):

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

The youtube-dl snap package (*youtube-dl*) is updated automatically in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # start with snap run youtube-dl
```

Show the version of youtube-dl snap package with `snap run youtube-dl --version`

Gydl (Graphical Youtube-dl) is a GUI wrapper around the already existing youtube-dl program. To install Gydl in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install gydl
```

When using Gydl, you have the option to download your YouTube video as a **Video** or **Audio**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Update: use [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) instead of [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl)! It's a fork off of `youtube-dl` and is much better-maintained and works much better!

---

These steps also solve this error:

```
WARNING: unable to download video info webpage: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

From the top of my answer here: [How to select video quality from youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097056/327339):

> ### How to install the *latest* version of `youtube-dl`
>
> See:
>
> 1. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/#installation
> 2. https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl
>
> Run these commands:
>
> ```bash
> # On Linux Ubuntu:
>
> # 1. Check your current version
> youtube-dl --version
>
> # 2.Uninstall your current version, if necessary
> sudo apt remove -y youtube-dl
>
> # 3. Now, install the latest version
> sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
> sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
>
> # 4. Check your current version to ensure it updated
> youtube-dl --version
> ```

Now use it to download a video:

```bash
youtube-dl -f best 'https://youtu.be/FWGC9SqA3J0'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the **latest** `youtube-dl` one can install [**GetDeb**](http://www.getdeb.net) [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).  For details about installing in *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS*, see [here](http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/16.04#how_to_install).

To get the *difference* between *getdeb* and *official Ubuntu* versions of `youtube-dl`, consider this output (as of 23.09.2016):

```
$ apt-cache policy youtube-dl
youtube-dl:
  Installed: 1:2016.09.19-1~getdeb1
  Candidate: 1:2016.09.19-1~getdeb1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2016.09.19-1~getdeb1 500
       500 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
       500 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2016.02.22-1 500
       500 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
       500 http://ubuntu.mirror.lrz.de/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

In above output, `2016.09.19-1` shows *getdeb* version and `2016.02.22-1` shows *official Ubuntu* version.

Answer (score 1):

Since youtube-dl autoupdate is disabled, try

```
sudo apt upgrade youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 1):

I had issues downloading youtube videos using the latest version of youtube-dl on Ubuntu 22.04. The youtube-dl version being 2021-12-17 from the Ubuntu repository using the apt package manager. This is the latest version of youtube-dl and is upto date on the Ubuntu repository.

To solve the problem I installed yt-dlp (a fork of youtube-dl), using

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp -o /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp  # Make executable
```

However, I had this error message when I ran

```
yt-dlp --version
```

it gave me

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

To solve this I had to **create a symlink** to python3 after locating it using the **whereis** command.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

After doing this I am able to download youtube videos again without any issues using yt-dlp.
Thank you devs for youtube-dl and yt-dlp.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017-11-11, if you are using Ubuntu, it seems that *precise* and *trusty* have too old versions of youtube-dl .

However, using the version from *Xenial* works. Otherwise, I'd suggest to install the latest version manually, as suggested in other answers.