# Youtube-dl not working

Tags: youtube-dl

I get the following error when I try to download video using `youtube-dl`.

```
WARNING: Warning: Falling back to static signature algorithm
ERROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: did you try the updated version. Try running `sudo youtube-dl -U` to update it

Comment: yes i have tried the updated version still doesn't work

Comment: I suggest you to install DownloadHelper in firefox. It is fast and effective. CLI takes a long time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot update youtube-dl](http://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/cannot-update-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you installed via apt-get? It seems this version is outdated.
This was happening to me:

```
$ sudo youtube-dl -U
It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.
```

You can install it from official sources: https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Using **curl**:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

If you do not have curl, you can alternatively use **wget**:

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

You can also use **pip**:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

You can also use **Homebrew**:

```
brew install youtube-dl
```

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/cannot-update-youtube-dl

Answer (score 11):

The solutions above didn't work for me.  I used the following commands from the official `youtube-dl` website.

http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2014.09.25/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: This is how youtube-dl should always be downloaded, in my opinion

Comment: confirm: the apt-get version of youtube-dl does not work, you have to download youtube-dl from its website, where you will find updated instructions to download the latest version - this post was copied from there but has an old download link. Note that you can also download it without sudo, like this `mkdir youtubedl; cd youtubedl; wget 'wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2016.03.14/youtube-dl -O youtube-dl' -O youtube-dl; ./youtube-dl` (use the latest download url as indicated in the [youtube-dl webpage](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)

Answer (score 3):

Those facing new problems with the `youtube-dl` with this error "*Warning: Falling back to static signature algorithm*" should first install `python-pip` (if they have not already installed it, of course) with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

and then, to fix the error, use

```
sudo pip install youtube-dl --upgrade
```

This is what worked for me this morning (as at the time of posting this answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear youtube-dl cache:

```
youtube-dl --rm-cache-dir
```

Source: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/6610:

Answer (score 1):

Install pip-python if you haven't already, then type :

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

This fixes the problem all right.

Answer (score 0):

Following fixed the issue. It is now working beautifully.

```
$ sudo apt-get install yasm
$ git clone git://git.libav.org/libav.git
$ cd libav
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Source: http://www.tecmint.com/record-ubuntu-desktop-screen-using-avconv/

Comment: -1 How is the installation of an upstream version of `avconv` from source going to alleviate a networking issue of `youtube-dl`? O.o

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded youtube-dl from https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2014.09.25/. I then did a chmod 777 youtube-dl, and ran the command. It asked me to upgrade via ./youtube-dl -U which upgraded me to the version 2015.12.13. I ran ./youtube-dl with the URL again and the problem had been solved.

Trying a pip upgrade on the default pip installation of youtube-dl did not do the upgrade or solve the problem, indicating that the pypi version might be outdated on bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and everything is working good now :

```
apt-get remove youtube-dl
apt-get update
apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Now it's work again, since those lines will re-installing the latest youtube-dl from server

Comment: You could also just do `apt-get install --reinstall youtube-dl` to achieve the same, I think...