# problem with youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl https://www.udemy.com/android-tutorial/learn/v4/t/lecture/131089
[udemy] 131089: Downloading webpage
[udemy] 131089: Downloading lecture JSON
[udemy] 25584: Enrolling in the course
[udemy] 131089: Downloading lecture JSON
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 403: FORBIDDEN (caused by 
HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

How I can solve this please?

Comment: Unable to test properly as a username and password is required. Have you run `youtube-dl --update` and tried again?

Comment: I suspect that the web site requires some form of authentication which lies outside of the scope of AU. Alternatively it's a bug in `youtube-dl` which would be off topic here too.

Comment: may be caused by the `youtube-dl` package you installed. Some of the repositories available to Ubuntu are out of date, or something like that. See answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/496417/youtube-dl-not-working?rq=1).

Comment: The error is not caused by a bug or an out-of-date version of youtube-dl. I got the same error when trying to download the same Udemy video using the latest version of youtube-dl.

Comment: This is a bad question with a good answer...  Why close?

Answer (score 2):

Use this command instead:

```
youtube-dl -u username@example.com -p yourpassword https://www.udemy.com/android-tutorial/learn/v4/t/lecture/131089
```

Use your email address login associated with Udemy as your login (`-u`) and your associated Udemy password (`-p`).