# Updating youtube-dl gives me ERROR: no write permission

Tags: youtube-dl

I couldn't download anymore with youtube-dl so I uninstalled it and followed this post https://askubuntu.com/a/380460/408472 and I still can't download anything. Now I get an `ERROR: Signature extraction failed`. Where it encourages me to update youtube-dl.

So I type `youtube-dl -U` and I get this:

```
ERROR: no write permissions on /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-U` flag updates `youtube-dl`.

To do this, you need root permissions to write in `/usr/local/bin/`. Try running it again with sudo.

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm still somewhat new to this. It tells me to restart youtube-dl. Is there a command I can type that does this?

Comment: @Rin007 Normally youtube-dl will close itself automatically. If it doesn't close itself, manually stop it with Ctrl+C on the command line... And remember to mark as solved if this helped out.

Answer (score 2):

Those commands should update the script (as well as install it), so you don't need to run `youtube-dl -U`, you can run them again to update it to the latest version.

However, if you want to run `youtube-dl -U`, you can use:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

to make your user the owner of the file, and then you should have write access.