# Can't download YouTube videos

Tags: youtube-dl

youtube-dl  is showing me this message all the time. What should I do?

```
$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-xPlsYmYXY
[youtube] Setting language
WARNING: unable to set language: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
[youtube] t-xPlsYmYXY: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

Comment: What is youtube-dl verison?

Comment: updated version.

Comment: I just tried downloading that video and it works fine. Are you sure you have the latest version of youtube-dl from https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html?

Comment: Remove the repository version and then follow this: http://askubuntu.com/a/380460/57576

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/809338/error-when-downloading-youtube-videos) maybe could help you. It seems youtube has restrictions to download some videos. Other tolls has the same problem. The last youtube-dl workaround this problem, at least until now.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Update: Similarly, instead using any third party PPA, you can use curl or wget command to install latest version of youtube-dl script as shown.

```
$ sudo curl https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
OR
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

After downloading the script, set the executable permission.

```
$ sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 0):

The protocol it might be violating might just be SSL, try using the `--no-check-certificate` or `--prefer-insecure` flags:

```
youtube-dl --no-check-certificate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-xPlsYmYXY
```

or

```
youtube-dl --prefer-insecure https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-xPlsYmYXY
```

It might also be a youtube-dl bug related specifically to your system settings. For instance, make sure that your system clock is accurate, else it could invalidate the SSL certificate.

You might want to read the rest of the [youtube-dl documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#user-content-workarounds).