# upgrading youtube-dl error

Tags: package-management, upgrade, pip, youtube-dl

My question is similar to the following, but it does not completely address the problem I am facing: [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

I have first tried this:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

which gives the output:

```
It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.
```

As mentioned in the answer, I have tried upgrading it using pip:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

It seems to have worked for many people. But for me it is giving the following error:

```
Installing collected packages: youtube-dl
  Found existing installation: youtube-dl 2016.2.22
Cannot uninstall 'youtube-dl'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Please instruct me on how to solve this issue and upgrade youtube-dl properly.

***Note:*** this probably should have been asked in the comment section of the mentioned question, but unfortunately I am unable to comment there, so I had to post it as a new question.

Comment: IMO, this should be its own question, not a comment.

Comment: How did you install `youtube-dl` in the first place? I'm guessing with APT, in which case you should uninstall it with APT: `sudo apt remove youtube-dl` then reinstall it  another way.

Comment: Please try `if [ ! -z $(dpkg -l | grep youtube-dl) ]; then sudo apt-get remove --purge youtube-dl; fi; sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Comment: Thank you. I have posted an answer based on your comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the insightful comments. 
As [wjandrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) and [cmak.fr](https://askubuntu.com/users/77093/cmak-fr) suggested, I tried removing youtube-dl first:

```
sudo apt remove youtube-dl
```

then reinstalled youtube-dl using pip:

```
sudo pip install youtube-dl
```

It installed the latest version of youtube-dl.