# How to update youtube-dl on ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: software-installation

When I type

```
sudo apt youtube-dl -U
```

I get this:

> ```
> E: Command line option 'U' [from -U] is not understood in combination with the other options.
> ```

so I tried `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

and I get: Command 'pip' not found

Comment: you don't have pip package, install it and run `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` again

Comment: `youtube-dl` is in the regular repos - so no `pip` needed. Why do you want to "update"?

Comment: Where did you find the `-U` flag? If you do `sudo apt update youtube-dl` what happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Comment: `sudo youtube-dl -U`

Answer (score 2):

That's the wrong command, and anyhow the version in the Ubuntu repos (installable through `apt`) does not receive updates very frequently and is many versions behind. Try removing the version you have installed now and following the [guidance on the youtube-dl downloads page](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html).

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl && sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

Now when you want to update you don't need apt, just use `sudo youtube-dl -U` (or use the longer-form --update in place of -U [as Hugo already posted](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085359/12864)).

If you prefer not to use sudo, try installing with pip to your home directory instead with `pip install --user youtube_dl` and then update regularly with `pip install --upgrade --user youtube_dl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Youtube-dl installed then you should be able to run it's own updater.

```
sudo youtube-dl --update
```