# Can not update youtube-dl

Tags: ubuntu-mate, youtube-dl

Trying to download an audio from youtube.

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILSr9BbhoJQ
[youtube] ILSr9BbhoJQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] ILSr9BbhoJQ: Downloading video info webpage
ERROR: ILSr9BbhoJQ: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Then I did this.

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo mkdir -pv /usr/local/bin
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

```
andy@7_~/Downloads$ youtube-dl -U
bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory
```

youtube-dl is in /usr/bin directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl) [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1049574/)

Comment: FYI:   I'd recommend removing the `apt` installed version if you are getting the `pip install` version. Problems may not appear at once, but may bite you later...  You didn't provide your release, I've usually filed a bug & within a few days (usually next day) the newer version is packaged and available for `apt` testing (on later releases esp.)

Comment: @karel That link is for a different error message. My errors do not have the word "pip" in them.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer (the linked one) is the only one that works, so I suggest that you try it anyway. You don't have to worry about pip anymore, because this answer does not have the word pip in it.

Comment: Have you tried this?
`sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/bin/youtube-dl
     sudo chmod a+rx /usr/bin/youtube-dl ` If you have the youtube-dl in the right folder you could try run the 2nd command.

Comment: That's not a native solution in Ubuntu and it uses `sudo` which is a high risk combination. Ubuntu Software has a package in it which can solve this problem.

Comment: They suggest do that way in the developers page: http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html. The problem with this particular package is that need be updated very frequently.

Comment: Ubuntu snap packages are updated frequently and aggressively compared to apt packages from the Ubuntu repositories. In particular the youtube-dl snap package is updated frequently and aggressively. The last time it was updated was 50 days ago.

Comment: The snap edge version used to be excellent, updated frequently. Now it seems the maintainer has run out of gas, can't recommend. What does `which youtube-dl` report? Note that if you're on 20.04  if you  use the wget method  it downloads a python2 version so you need to have the `python-is-python2` package installed for it to work...

Comment: I see so many responses. I get the impression that downloading a youtube video is a hit or miss thing with youtube-dl.

Answer (score -1):

This came from a Mozilla support group.

Clip Grab

Download it from here.

https://clipgrab.org/faqs/howto-download-youtube-video

Just double click it to run the program.