# How to set environment variable for the updated youtube-dl installed from pip3?

Tags: python, video, environment-variables, pip, youtube-dl

I referred to an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl) to install youtube-dl using pip.
Although youtube-dl was installed by default in my Ubuntu 20.04, by apt, but it was outdated and showing errors.

Besides, I used pip3 to install it by the command,

`pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl`

and also uninstalled the outdated youtube-dl by the apt package manager.

When I use the command `pip3 show youtube-dl`, it shows an output as following:

```
Name: youtube-dl
Version: 2020.6.16.1
Summary: YouTube video downloader
Home-page: https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl
Author: Ricardo Garcia
Author-email: ytdl@yt-dl.org
License: Unlicense
Location: /home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

I guess now I have to set it as environment variable so I can use it, since I am not able to use any of its commands, for eg.,

`youtube-dl --version`

gives me an output:

`bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory`

Comment: Symlink the Python application to someplace on your $PATH, so the shell can find it.

Comment: how to do that? will that work? for I've manually entered the folder there, and tried the command, but it was of no use

Comment: See `man ln` for how to create a symlink. The shell looks for applications in $PATH; your is not in $PATH, hence the error. DON'T move the folder; that will break things; move it back.

Comment: Please can you give a detailed help.

Comment: What is the complete path to the youtube-dl executable?

Comment: The files downloaded recide at /home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube-dl

Comment: If you use that path, does the application work?

Comment: When I go the path, and type, youtube-dl --version , again no output. Maybe I'm missing some bin folder, I'll let you know.

Comment: Try: `/home/vivek/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/youtube-dl --version` You don't need to go to the path. You simply need to be specific about the executable's location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `youtube-dl` script is probably located in the `/home/vivek/.local/bin` directory. In that case all you need to do is to log out and log in again. By doing so the code in your `~/.profile` file will automatically add the directory to `PATH`.