# Youtube-dl Error

Tags: youtube-dl

I've been using ubuntu for a while. I reset my windows laptop and reinstalled youtube-dl. Everytime I try and use it, it comes up with the message "Error: Youtube said: This video is unavailable". I tried updating my version as it is the 2018.03.14 but it says it is the latest version. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try updating `youtube-dl`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl