# Cant use the updated youtube-dl

Tags: updates, python, python3, youtube, youtube-dl

I have the following youtube-dl version

```
  youtube-dl --version
    2020.03.24
```

I would like to update it with the following command

```
pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
Requirement already up-to-date: youtube-dl in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2020.11.12)
```

It seems that I already have it updated to 2020.11.12 version, but when I check the version, it does not update it.

```
$ youtube-dl --version
2020.03.24
```

The question is: is my youtube-dl running on Python2? how can I change it to run with Python3? how can I update my youtube-dl to the latest version?

Comment: Just in case, you may want to check whether you installed `youbute-dl` by multiple methods. For example, the 2020.03.24 version may come from a `deb` package that you've installed parallel to the `pip` package. Check which binary the command `youtube-dl` is using with `whereis youtube-dl`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because youtube-dl is being accessed from somewhere else in the path.

Check the version this way:

```
python3 -m youtube-dl --version
```

If it shows the right version you're looking for, it means that somewhere else in your path there is another youtube-dl which your using, you can use the updated version of youtube-dl like this: `python3 -m youtube-dl` or you can delete the other youtube-dl from your path.

Comment: /usr/bin/python3: No module named youtube-dl is the output of the command you recommended me :-(

Answer (score 1):

The `apt` version of `youtube-dl` [has the version number](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/youtube-dl) `2020.03.24` in Ubuntu 20.04.

To uninstall it and install the latest version of `youtube-dl`, enter the following commands one by one.

```
sudo apt remove youtube-dl
pip3 install --user youtube-dl
```

The `pip` version of `youtube-dl` resides in `.local/bin/` in your home folder.

To add it to your path, add the following lines to the hidden `.profile` file in your home folder (create it, if it already does not exist. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files). Restart your computer for the change to take effect.

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: I did what you asked me. The first command uninstalls the existing youtube-dl. The second command outputs me the following: Requirement already satisfied: youtube-dl in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2020.11.12). How can I tell Ubuntu where youtube-dl is? thanks.

Comment: @Madeyra I have edited my answer to add this information