# Youtube, Dailymotion video playback Firefox problem

Tags: youtube

product: GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation,
Nvidia driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470,
Ubuntu 22.10,
Kubuntu

I've installed the codecs from
"sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras"

And I've changed the Firefox setting
“gfx.webrender.all”  to true

I used to get errors playing Youtube/Dailymotion video all the time before doing the above changes, now playback is a bit better now and only get the odd but predictable error. The other problem is where I try to rewind the back to a previous time, the video freezes but I can still hear the audio playing in real time. And only way to fix this is to pause the video for about 6 seconds and only then will it plays normally again.

Thanks

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem! So I just needed to make an exception for cookies for Youtube in Firefox. Interesting I had to do that for Linux but not Windows.