# I have to update youtube-dl

Tags: pip, youtube-dl

I have open video downloader, which worked before. But now it doesn't. I tried to install pip by putting ensure pip in Python 3.11 but I don't know how to change the greater than signs. Or if you have to. I did hours of research into this. All into youtube-dl and pip. But I never learned how to update it. Do I even have to? I'd love some help.

Comment: Suggest you switch to https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp

Comment: youtube isnt a fan of youtube-dl and will be forever trying to break it. the latest incarnation of that is by putting regex in the url, which breaks youtube-dl parser. 
maybe someone has made a fix for that.

Comment: Try Parabolic (previously known as Tube Converter), a nice GUI based on yt-dlp. GitHub: https://github.com/NickvisionApps/Parabolic, Flatpak: https://flathub.org/apps/org.nickvision.tubeconverter, Snap: `sudo snap install tube-converter`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I update youtube-dl?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Comment: Parabolic worked for me when others like youtube-dl, command line or python3 method failed. strange since Parabolic? works based on it.

Comment: I spoke too soon, parabolic also failed, but only after pretending to download it to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

According to youtube-dl official documentation, you could try

```
youtube-dl -U
```

or

```
youtube-dl --update
```

or even

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Comment: I had to do the pip install (3rd option) to get it to work - the first and the second options did not return any errors but youtube downloads kept failing.

Comment: I have no idea why. Anyway, if you find my answer helpful, please be kind and upvote, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

latest version 2021.12.17 no updates after

**NOT** working anymore (at some point, to make you pay for it, utube enforced no download policy to make you pay for premium)

sorry ...